# Change WPF Combobox to react on Mouse down

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

The WPF ComboBox isn't great when used on a touch screen.
User has to tap on the ComboBoxItem and release within a certain area etc, within a certain time frame.
Basically a mouse down followed by a mouse up.
If user taps (or same as clicks) slowly there is no selection of the ComboBoxItem.

To improve this I like to change the ComboBox item so it react on the MouseDown event instead,
this will make the selection of the ComboBox item much more natural when using a finger on touch screen..

My idea was to create a CustomComboBoxItem that inherits from the ComboBoxItem.

```
public class CustomComboBoxItem : ComboBoxItem
{
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        IsSelected = true;
        OnSelected(e);
    }

}
```

But have to got this to work.
Keep getting:

Message=A style intended for type 'CustomComboBoxItem' cannot be applied to type 'ComboBoxItem'.

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Do you have your own combobox style / control template defined?  If so, you MAY need to qualify it to recognize your derived CustomComboBoxItem.

Comment: This combobox is no using XAML tags with ComboBoxItem, instead it is typlkically using a binding to a prsentation model or collection. Example:
-----------------------------------
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SpeciesEnums}, Converter={StaticResource SeussEnumValueToPresentationModelConverter}, ConverterParameter='UseIntValue'}"

Answer (score 0):

I do not think there is a need for **CustomComboBoxItem**. All you have to do is call the `touch` events and lock it when it touches an item, so that wherever you go on the screen, that item is selected and unlocked the first time you touch it.

[***touchdevice***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.touchdevice?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

[***mousedevice.capture***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.input.mousedevice.capture?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#overloads)

```
bool IsTouch = false;
private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewTouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)sender;
    e.TouchDevice.Capture(comboBoxItem);
    IsTouch = true;
}

private void ComboBoxItem_PreviewTouchUp(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem comboBoxItem = (ComboBoxItem)sender;
    comboBoxItem.ReleaseTouchCapture(e.TouchDevice);
    IsTouch = false;
}

private void ComboBoxItem_TouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if(IsTouch)
    {
       //do work.............................
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you add these subscriptions in a CustomComboBox class or in the usercontrol cs file? 
Or how do you access each ComboBoxItem?

Comment: Where comboBox is used. in UserControl

Comment: The xaml looks like this:
<ComboBox
                x:Name="speciesComboBox"
                DisplayMemberPath="Description"
                ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource SpeciesEnums}, Converter={StaticResource SeussEnumValueToPresentationModelConverter}, ConverterParameter='UseIntValue'}"
                SelectedValue="{Binding SeussStudyEx.Study.Patient.SpeciesId, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
                SelectedValuePath="EnumValue"
                Text="{StaticResource Words_Species}" />

Comment: SO in other words I don't add the ComboBoxItem as XAML tags, instead the ItemsSource is a binding

Comment: So these are the events you should use. Do you know how to use the events?

Comment: I solved this by creating a CustomCombobox class is using a custom style with a control template including a custom scroller: SelectorScroller
Then in CustomCombobox method OnAppltTemplate find the scroller object and add events:
 _selectorScroller.ScrollChanged += HandleSelectorScrollerOnScrollChanged;
_selectorScroller.PreviewMouseDown +=HandleSelectorScrollerOnPreviewMouseDown;
_selectorScroller.PreviewTouchDown += HandleSelectorScrollerOnPreviewTouchDown;